# Ubuntu 12.04, Can hear the sound but Sound option in settings shows no sound card

Tags: soundcard

I have weired issue. I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04. Then I installed Nvidia drives for my graphics card. I executed the command "modprobe nvidia" after installing the Nvidia drivers and rebooted. After reboot, sound indicator in top panel is disabled and I can't control the volume from there. I opened Settings > Sound and it does not show any sound card installed. However, I can hear the sound. Please help.

Output of lspci | grep Audio

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Output of lsmod | grep snd

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32191  4 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    73851  1 
snd_hda_intel          33367  0 
snd_hda_codec         134156  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97188  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_timer              29990  1 snd_pcm
snd                    78855  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_timer
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue is resolved now. I was logged in with root. I logged out and logged in with another user and it worked.

Comment: Now your problem is solved, you should accept your own answer so future visitors can see this answer solved the problem.